# stock(paper) delivery to home

Tags: stocks, online-brokerage

I want my stocks delivered from online broker to my home. How to do that? Is that possible?(In russia there are no stock papers, there are only so called depositariums where stocks are and where you can get papers which says that stocks are yours.)

I'm asking whether that is possible for US citizen and whether this possible for foreigner which uses (for exameple) Interactive Brokers account.

Is such a paper contains my name or can be stolen?

Comment: Some info [here](http://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/06/stockcertificate.asp). You'll probably have to ask the company directly, your broker might be able to help, but I don't think they're obligated to.

Comment: To add slightly, what is supported will depend primarily on the issuer (and their transfer agent or registrar), secondarily on your broker, and probably not at all on your citizenship or residence. Although the cost to mail paper to you (usually by certified, registered, or similarly protected mail) may depend partly on your mailing address. Even though a certificate has your name a stolen one could be falsely transferred if you don't report the theft promptly. And you most likely won't be able to sell it on a market without first converting back to book or street registration.

Comment: It looks like my broker charges $500 to issue the certificates but it's possible; Google search shows $200-575 across major brokerages.  Probably costs similar to deposit into a brokerage account to sell it.  Treat this like a fine art and do it for the scripophily if you're going to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Getting "physical stocks" will in most cases only be for the "fun of it". Most stocks nowadays are registered electronically and thus the physical stock will be of no value - it will just be a certificate saying that you own X amount of shares in company X; but this information is at the same time registered electronically.

Stocks are *not* like bearer bonds, the certificate itself contains no value and is registered to each individual/entity.

Because the paper itself is worthless, stealing it will not affect your amount of stock with the company.

This is true for *most* stocks - there may exist companies who live in the 70s and do not keep track of their stock electronically, but I suspect it will only be very few (and most likely very small and illiquid companies).